# An Implementation for native extension was not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I'm having a little trouble creating an .IPA file in Flash CS5.5, once I change the app.xml to include all my extensions (SWC's which have already been added to the AS3 library path), I'm thrown the below error:

[image]

```
<extensions>
    <extensionID>so.cuo.platform.admob</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.adobe.ane.stageAd</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

I decided to test publishing an .IPA from my .FLA file in Flash Professional CC and it worked the first time without having to change anything, which shows that it's Flash Professional CS5.5 which doesn't seem to want to work (but unfortunately I can't use CC).

I've updated all the players, updated SDK/AIR but I'm still thrown the error only after I include the extensions in the .XML, has anyone found a solution for this particular error when publishing .IPA's using Flash Professional CS5.5?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you should be adding SWC, and not ANE files?